# Pulling contents of looped tkinter Entry widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a certain range in a variable. I don't know how long that range is. This range is going to be in a loop. Every time the loop 'loops' I want to create to tkinter Entry widgets. But, later, I want to get the contents of this. How can I accomplish this? I know there are a few duplicates of this question, but I couldn't solve it with their answers.

SAMPLE CODE:

```
for i in range(0,x):
    tk.Entry(root).pack()
    tk.Entry(root).pack()
```

Comment: Just append your entry to a list or a dict. Note that you need to append a reference of the entry, so you need to first define the entry as a variable, append to a list, and then pack it separately

Comment: Thank you, but as I mentioned, I don't know how long the range is. I can't make any variables for it, because of that.

Comment: Why not? You can define the variable inside the loop. Just put a = tk.Entry(root) and append a to a list outside of the loop

Comment: I had similar issue. [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359527/add-multiple-entries-and-retrieve-data-from-them-dynamically)

Comment: I get what you're saying now, Henry Yik. See my answer how I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was inspired by Henry Yik and got this solution:

- Make a list
- Loop
- In loop: Create widget and append to list
- In loop: Get the widget from the list and pack it.

See this sample code:

```
w = []
for i in range(0,x):
    w.append(tk.Entry(root))
    w[i].pack()
```